# Boost Regulator issue at high load

Tags: boost, converter

I'm trying to understand the causes of output voltage dropping as my load increases on a boost converter.
The switcher i'm using is a [TPS61093](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61093.pdf) from TI. I'm troubleshooting a circuit that someone else built. It is built exactly as the reference design shows below, except Vout = 12.1V.

```
Vin=4V
Vout=12.1V 
L1=10uH
R1=232K
R2=10K
R3, C6 open
R4 short
```

The issue is that on my bench:

- As I increase the load past 45mA, I start seeing a drop in the voltage.
  50mA -> Vout=11.11V, this drops further as I further increase the load.
- I see on the input a Iin = 264mA (current input to the smps) which seems excessive given I'm pulling only 50mA. And this current increases also with increased load.

Any idea what's possibly going on?

[image]

- My input drops only by 10mV when my output is out of regulation.
- The enable pin is actually pulled high through a 100k
- IND, WIRE-WOUND, 10uH, ±10%, 380mA, 0603, with .Rdc = 0.34Ω. The SRF is 32Mhz
- As I pointed out. The designer went with the actual ref design from TI. and that design does not include C6. I'd think C6 would only improve the feedback loop stability for fast transient load or it has a different purpose.
- The output capacitor is 12uF.
- My power supply is not current limited.

Comment: What is your input supply voltage doing when the output is not in regulation - is it staying at 4V or also dropping? Your enable pin doesn't appear to be linked in your diagram. What is the spec of your inductor? Why is C6 open circuit and not 10nF like on pg 14 of data sheet (higher output capacitance)? What is your output capacitance in reality?

Comment: You also mention that the input current seems excessive - are you sure you haven't got current limiting set from your power supply. It's not excessive if your power supply into the device is dropping to maybe 2.3V. Power out = 0.555 watts and power is will be about 0.6 watts.

Comment: My expected max load is 200mA. So the Inductor current rating should be fine. the issue is that when i apply a 40mA load on the output i see more than 200mA of input current, which is getting close to the overload current of the IC

Comment: 12V*40mA == 2.4*200mA, so if your input voltage is on the order of 3.0V, that would be reasonable. What is the resistance of the inductor, what is the actual input voltage, and what efficiency do you expect?
Nevermind, I saw the additional answers -- they are quite likely right; your inductor has way too much resistance, leading to poor efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inductor is awfully tiny for this application. For one thing, it needs to be rated to handle the *input* current, which is going to be more than 3× the output current.

Remember, the inductor current passes to the output only when the regulator's switch is off. Since you're going for a voltage multiplication of 3×, the switch duty cycle will be 2/3, and the diode will be conducting only 1/3 of the time. If you want to draw 200 mA at the output, the inductor is going to be carrying an *average* current of about 700 mA.

The switching freqeuncy of the regulator is fixed at 1.2 MHz. At 2/3 duty cycle, this means the switch is on for nominally 555 ns. With an input voltage of 4V and an inductor of 10 µH, this means that the peak-to-peak ripple current is going to be

$$\Delta I = \frac{V}{L} \Delta t = \frac{4 V}{10 \mu H} 555 ns = 222 mA$$

This means that the peak current will be about 111 mA higher than the average current. You want the saturation current of the inductor to be a comfortable margin above the peak value.

When your inductor saturates, you'll see the exact symptoms you're getting: poor regulation and poor efficiency.

Also, with a peak current of around 800 mA, even the 0.34Ω of series resistance is going to cut into your efficiency with a drop of almost 300 mV, which is nearly 10% of your input voltage.

Comment: This means that with Iavg =Iload = 50mA i should expect a peak current of 161mA which is still between the inductor's specs. Nevertheless, at 50mA load my output starts going out of regulation with dmm showing 230mA at the input...Sorry for insisting but is there something i don't understand ?

Comment: I_avg **does not equal** I_load! This is a key point. If I_load = 50 mA, then I_avg is *at least* 150 mA (before you consider the efficiency losses from the inductor's resistance and the drop across the switching devices), and I_peak is over 260 mA, which is pushing your tiny inductor awfully hard. You really need to pick a different inductor that has a saturation current over 1A.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Your designer chose too small of an inductor by a factor of 2 or 3

- Input = 4.0V , 264mA (=1.06W)
- output= 11.11V, 50mA (=0.55W)

Indeed , regulation is poor, and efficiency is <50%.  This because Input current is  saturating the inductor.

The guidelines have strict rules about the Inductor. The examples given are  rated for >=1A at10uH but this is the current for which the inductance holds its value to 50% reduction. They are also much bigger parts. From 4x4 to 5.2x5.2 while your 0603 is only 1.5x0.75 [mm]

Get the L out of there.  Toko is the best  here!  Go for 1.09A Toko part.

- VFB ref should be 500.55mV +-1% at room-temp.
- switch duty cycle should be 66% or so

Review the Imax calculations from formula (5) in specs above.

I = 1/(10 *1 * 0.375 ) = 267 mA x3  = 800 mA min at 25'C  ( duty cycle requirements)

Comment: Joe. i followed you till the last line. How exactly did you derive the max output current from the formula on the datasheet ? Are you referring to the I_Lpeak ? I guess i'm trying to understand how you came up with 267mA

Comment: No that was IL-p-p and if Vo=11.2 in the last term using Vo=11.2 , (Vo+0.8-Vi) =8 and thus 1/(1/8+1/4)= 0.375 is correct.  Note that when L drops from saturation, I increases tending to cause more current and more saturation and more voltage drop , so L saturation is the cause of Ip-p max peaking and Vo drops rapidly, note that. If I used 11.11V it result was 0.3764

Comment: I suggest use a spreadsheet and calculate the Vo drop vs  I_pp then the incremental ratio is ESR or regulation of output.  At your threshold ESR is around 6 Ohms assume L drops with load and repeat.although saturation is non-linear, it has a hard limit effect on Imax in load dump beacuse stored energy peaks